# Write Selenium Test to test text wrapping?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write the selenium test using selenium 2.0 for the attached scenario. [image: Test Scenario]

HTML code is as follows

`<div width="100px" style = "background-color:blue">
This%is%Normal%Text%on%page%without%dynamic%view%and%not%width%set.
</div>`

I need to verify whether text is wrapping or not. Text should wrap in the 2nd scenario

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sahil

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it goes too deep to browser's internals so it is not possible with Selenium. Maybe you can check the **height ow wrapping element** (div) if it exceeds height of line, but it looks fragile to me.

Answer (score 0):

May be should try the url encode/uncode to see if that particular text is encoded or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the text is overflowed.

```
public boolean isElementOverflowed(CoreLocator element) {
    return (boolean) coreDriver.executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollWidth > arguments[0].clientWidth",
            element.getWebElement());
}
```

and call it in your code.